# Django model reference like loop?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I want to know how to django model like circular reference... like,

```
class Family(models.Model): 
   fname = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
   member_id = models.ForeignKey(Member) 

class Member(models.Model):
   name = model.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
   family_id = models.ForeignKey(Family)
```

these two Familiy and Member is my models. i want some circular reference...

Main goal is to bind member under each families. that's works fine. but some query i just parse only Family table and i want Main Member of that particular family like, i want family head for each family means what shall i do?

Explain the circular reference or any better method available than that. or shall i do foreign key for both.  please help to get solution.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the right approach, you shouldn't have circular reference in your models. If you want to have relationships like that, depend on the requirement:

1. If one person can only has one family, put family as foreign key in `Member` model.
2. If one person can have multiple families, put `member` as `ManyToMany` field in `Family` model.

Also, don't name your field `member_id` or `family_id`. Django model is not just database design, but python class code as well. Try to use `member` and `family` instead.

<sub>Gentle suggestion: Please don't put any description of your question in the code block tags. Also try to make your wording as formal as possible(cap first).</sub>

**Edit**:

If you want to get member details of a family, it's easy in django as well:

```
# model
class Family(models.Model): 
   fname = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)

class Member(models.Model):
   name = model.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
   family = models.ForeignKey(Family)

# get a family
family = Family.objects.get(id=1)
# get all family members
all_family_members = family.member_set.all()
```

[Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) about following the relationship backwards.

Comment: one person have just one family only. i need corresponding member details from my family table. i need solution for that .. in circular reference too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with having two models having a foreign key of each other. You must allow nulls for family_head because you cannot create members without a family.

```
class Family(models.Model): 
   fname = models.CharField()
   family_head = models.ForeignKey(Member, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL) 

class Member(models.Model):
   name = model.CharField()
   family = models.ForeignKey(Family)
```

You can now create a Family with a null family_head then the members of the family and then set the family_head after checking to see if family_head is actually one of the family members.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the code, The method called circular reference which is worked for me..

in model use function instead of Foreignkey on both tables like below, 
class Family(models.Model): 
   fname = models.CharField()

   def get_member(self):
        return Member.objects.get(family=self,family_head=True) 

class Member(models.Model):
   name = model.CharField()
   family = models.ForeignKey(Family)

and to get the expected value just call this line from your django view or something else. 
print "get member",Family.object.get(id=1).get_member()
#above line will return table object. so if you want certain field use like this, name : Family.object.get(id=1).get_member().name
```